How to find the Bayesian estimator for θ using the posterior mean with the prior for θ being a double exponential distribution?
This is the setup problem: 
Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are i.i.d. samples from the $N(θ,1)$ distribution. Assume the prior for $θ$ is a double exponential distribution, i.e. $f(θ)=\frac{1}{2} e^{−|θ|}$.

Derive the posterior distribution for θ.
Find the Bayesian estimator for θ using the posterior mean.
How does the choice of prior influence the posterior distribution?

For the first part, $f(x_i|\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{(x_i-\theta)^2}{2}}$ and $Θ \sim h(\theta)=\frac{1}{2} e^{−|θ|}$ gives
$$L(X_1,X_2,...,X_n|\theta)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}})^ne^{-\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\theta)^2/2}$$
$$L(X_1,X_2,...,X_n|\theta)h(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}^n}exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\theta)^2−|θ|)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}^n}exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i^2-2x_i\theta+\theta^2)−|θ|)$$
$\sum^n_{i=1}x_i$ can be written as $n\bar{x}$. Then I got
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}^n}exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2-2n\bar{x}\theta+n\theta^2)−|θ|)$$
Ignoring all the terms without $\theta$, I got
$$k(\theta|x)∝e^{n\bar{x}\theta-n\theta^2/2-|θ|}$$ This is my posterior distribution for $\theta$. This can also become $e^{-\frac{n}{2}(\bar{x}-\theta)^2-|θ|}$, but I don't know if it would help. 
For part 2, I think I should be using $\mathcal{L}(\theta, \delta(X_1,X_2,...,X_n))=(\theta-\delta)^2$. This way$\delta(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=\mathbb{E}(Θ|x_1,···,x_n)$. However, this results in
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\theta e^{-\frac{n}{2}(\bar{x}-\theta)^2-|θ|}d\theta$$ This is where I am stuck. Is this integral computable? The alternative is trying to compute $argmin\int_{-\infty}^\infty k(\theta|X)(\theta-\delta)^2d\theta$, which seems even worse. How should I proceed or where should I be rethinking the strategy?

Maybe better to ask in stats.stackexchange.com

The posterior density is
\begin{align}
\pi(\theta\mid \boldsymbol x) &\propto \exp\left\{-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\theta)^2 -|\theta|\right\}
\\& \propto \exp\left\{-\frac12\left(n\theta^2 -2\theta n\overline x+2|\theta|\right)\right\} \quad, \,\theta \in \mathbb R.
\end{align}
If you split this into separate cases for $\theta>0$ and $\theta<0$ and complete the squares, I think you end up with two normal kernels in each case:
$$
\pi(\theta\mid \boldsymbol x) \propto  
\begin{cases}
\exp\left[-\frac{n}2\left\{\theta-\left(\overline x-\frac1n\right)\right\}^2\right] &, \text{ if }\theta>0 \\
\exp\left[-\frac{n}2\left\{\theta-\left(\overline x+\frac1n\right)\right\}^2\right] &, \text{ if }\theta<0
\end{cases}
$$
This suggests that the posterior is a mixture of two truncated normal distributions. The posterior mean then follows from the means of the truncated normal distributions.
